# I need help Select Sum in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need help to help me correct my php function in codeigniter.
I have a database; I want addirionner all values ​of " from_user_id ".

[Check data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYQ6i.png)

I use this sql to get the desired result.

```
 SELECT SUM(kiff_envoi+kiff_recu+visite_recu+profile_visite+da_recu+da_envoi+topic_poster+repon_topic+conv_envoi+conv_recu) AS total_stats FROM score WHERE from_user_id = ?
```

In codeingniter I​ use this function.
It allows me to check if " from_user_id " exists, if it exists, we calculate the total different tables and we update the result in " total_stats ". If " from_user_id " does not exist, create it.
But my function does not return me the right result.

I had to make a big mistake but I do not know where!
Does someone could help me please.

```
public function count_tout_stats($user_id) //total des stats 

{
$this->db->select_sum(conv_recu, conv_envoi, repon_topic, etc...);
$query = $this->db->from('score'); 
$this->db->where('from_user_id', $user_id);

$total_stats = $this->db->count_all_results();

if ($this->ttl_stats_score($user_id) > 0) // Check if exists  
{
    $data = array( 
        'total_stats' => $total_stats
    );
    $this->db->where('from_user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update('score', $data);
}
else
{
    $data = array( 
        'from_user_id' => $user_id,
        'total_stats' => $total_stats
    );
    $this->db->insert('score', $data);  
}

return $total_stats;
} 

public function ttl_stats_score($user_id)
{
$this->db->where('from_user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->from('score');

return $this->db->count_all_results(); 
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Violette

Comment: Which part is not working?/

Comment: I think my problem is that!

'$total_stats = $this->db->count_all_results();'

or that

'return $this->db->count_all_results(); '

It all seems to work except the results. Currently , he returned me the value "1" in " total_stats " instead of 112 for the " from_user_id " 21132 , for example.

Comment: `count_all_results()` will give the count.

Comment: @VioletteP use `row_array()` to get your desire result.

Comment: yes, but it does not work !

Comment: what array() value you are getting in `row_array()` method. use `print_r($total_stats)` to see your result.

Comment: Thank you very much Yash but how to use row_array() I done ? can you help me please !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$this->db->select('(kiff_envoi+kiff_recu+visite_recu+profile_visite+da_recu+da_envoi+topic_poster+repon_topic+conv_envoi+conv_recu) as total_stats');
$this->db->from('score'); 
$this->db->where('from_user_id', $user_id);

$result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
print_r($result);
```

You will get your result